# SSL site still says there is insecure content

Tags: google-chrome, ssl

I have searched through a new site I am setting up multiple times and I can not find any insecure content. Maybe a second pair of eyes can help.

Can you guys let me know what I am missing to prevent chrome from putting an X over my SSL icon.

Firefox and IE don't show any SSL errors.

Site is dorknerd.com

Thanks.

Comment: I have absolutely no problems in chrome...

Comment: You may be interested in [this answer on ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/a/349992/47187).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i got this from your site:

[image]

Looks like some of your javascript breaks the secure connection...

If you dont allready, you should consider using chromes developer tools. (press F12 or ctrl+shift+j to use them) They will most of the time be able to help you out.

Comment: That's strange, I looked at the same script and see it as https:://pagead2.googlesyndication.com...... (don't mind second : --- only way i could put it in comments as far as i know)

Comment: Well i don't think the error is on your side, the script may be using ajax functions to gather information about the site or the visitors, and when doing so the script might use a http connection instead of https

Comment: View my edit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297904/serving-ads-via-https

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any errors in Chrome either. If you're trying to make sure a site is not pulling unsecure content behind an SSL, then do a ctrl+f (find) for http... hrefs do not matter, only content you are embedding through includes, css, javascript etc... Look through the html output of the page through a view source, search it and see if you see unsecure content.... but as I said i don't see an in Chrome (nor FF, or IE)

Edit:

I did some searching and I believe this is your problem: [Serving ads via HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297904/serving-ads-via-https)